# Building Hadoop with Maven - "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (create-testdirs)"

Tags: maven, hadoop

I'm trying to build the Hadoop trunk using Maven. I got the project with svn. But then, I tried `mvn clean install`. But I'm getting the following error:

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [1.616s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... FAILURE [0.322s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM .................... SKIPPED

.... etc ....
.... etc ....

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.361s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jun 15 20:52:13 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/43M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (create-testdirs) on project hadoop-project: Error executing ant tasks: /home/sreejith/svn/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (create-testdirs) on project hadoop-project: Error executing ant tasks: /home/sreejith/svn/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml (No such file or directory)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing ant tasks: /home/sreejith/svn/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml (No such file or directory)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:287)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sreejith/svn/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.fileWrite(FileUtils.java:470)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.writeTargetToProjectFile(AntRunMojo.java:499)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:226)
... 21 more
```

I googled all I could. Could someone give me a clue why this is happening?

Comment: "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/sreejith/svn/hadoop-trunk/hadoop-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml (No such file or directory)"...Do you have this?

Comment: Just skip the tests with `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: @Tariq No there doesn't to be such an xml file at the moment. But it should be auto-generated right?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Just tried doing that. Still no progress. I'm guessing its a problem with that plugin (maven-antrun-plugin). How are such plugin problems usually approached?

Comment: Do you have ant installed? Check if it is in the path with `which ant`

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Yes. It returned /usr/bin/ant

Comment: I guess that the `target/antrun` directory doesn't get generated, maybe you want to add the `antrun` dir and then start with `mvn install -DskipTests`

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Actually that got me in the right direction. I couldn't make the directory. That got me wondering. I did a `chown` and did the build. Voila! Build Success. Thank you!

Comment: This is what I was asking. DO you have this path?(And if you have, owner permissions should be appropriate)..Anyways, you got it working..Thanks to TJ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution. Do a `sudo chown -R username parent-directory` if you haven't already. Now try, `mvn install -DskipTests`. Everything should go fine and you should get `BUILD SUCCESS`.

P.S: Thanks ThomasJungblut

Answer (score 1):

Try running 'protoc' and verify that it has the right GCC libraries installed. That was a problem I had on a build from source. It happened when I ran the command in a window where I had sourced a bunch of library configs for a software program, which seemed to screw up the proper library loading.

I had built and installed the google protoc from source, and downloaded maven, and installed, and worked off the raw git of hadoop-common.  No other prep work changed from standard Centos6.